# swf file terminates automatically after publishing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I create app using flash cs 5.5. It works fine. Then I started using flash cs6. The app was running fine until today. It runs fine but the problem is when i tried to publish it, it start playing but after some time(about 30 secs), swf file terminates itself. There is no problem in using cs5.5. It's just when i tried to publish it, it runs and swf file is close itself. Do any one have any idea what might be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "the swf file terminates itself", are you talking about the standalone flash player? Normally if this happens, it's because an error was thrown, but if you're not using the debug player, you won't see it, it'll just close.

Download the debugger player here: http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html and run your swf in debug mode (so all the debug symbols are present and you get the most complete error message). This should give you an idea of what the error is, and where to go to fix it.

NOTE: to know if you're running in the debug player or not, right-click on the swf in the player, and if you see an option for "Show redraw regions", then it's the debug player

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I mean "swf file terminates itself", I mean when I try to publish it. And the problem is solved. It turns out I can't turn my simulator off in cs 6. If I close simulator the swf file also closes by itself after some moments. Thanks anyway.